Why does my .net 8.0 winforms app throw a 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified' exception on the target server?
I created a new .net 8.0 winforms project in vs2022, it includes the latest webview2 nuget package.
This is the full project code:
myawesomeprogram.cs
namespace myawesomenamespace
{
  internal static class myawesomeprogram
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
      Application.Run(new myawesomeform());
    }
  }
}

myawesomeform.designer.cs
namespace myawesomenamespace
{
  partial class myawesomeform
  {
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing && (components != null))
      {
        components.Dispose();
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      myawesomewebview = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();          
      ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)myawesomewebview).BeginInit();
      SuspendLayout();

      myawesomewebview.AllowExternalDrop = true;
      myawesomewebview.CreationProperties = null;
      myawesomewebview.DefaultBackgroundColor = Color.White;
      myawesomewebview.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      myawesomewebview.Location = new Point(0, 0);
      myawesomewebview.Name = "myawesomewebview";
      myawesomewebview.Size = new Size(800, 450);
      myawesomewebview.TabIndex = 4;
      myawesomewebview.ZoomFactor = 1D;

      AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(7F, 15F);
      AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
      ClientSize = new Size(800, 450);
      Controls.Add(myawesomewebview);
      Name = "myawesomeform";
      Text = "myawesomeform";
      WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
      Load += myawesomeform_Load;
      ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)myawesomewebview).EndInit();
      ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    private Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 myawesomewebview;
  }
}

myawesomeform.cs
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

namespace myawesomenamespace
{
  public partial class myawesomeform : Form
  {
    private Random? myawesomerandom;

    public myawesomeform()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void myawesomeform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      CoreWebView2Environment? myawesomeenvironment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync();
      await myawesomewebview.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(myawesomeenvironment);

      myawesomerandom = new Random();
      await Task.Delay(myawesomerandom.Next(1000, 2000));
      myawesomewebview.Source = new Uri("http://lixxx.co.uk");
      await Task.Delay(myawesomerandom.Next(1000, 2000));
      myawesomewebview.Source = new Uri("http://lmfgtfy.co.uk");
    }
  }
}

The publish profile is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>C:\dev\_pub</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

I right click the project in solution explorer and select publish, then use the publish screen.
It runs on my development machine perfectly well.
I configured a publish profile with a release configuration, a .net 8.0 windows target framework, a win x64 target runtime, a self contained deployment mode using the single file and ready to run compilation options.
The published .exe file, in its published directory, runs correctly.
When I cut and paste the entire published directory onto a 64 bit AMD server, running windows server 2022 and run the .exe, the application loads and immediately displays an unhandled error exception dialogue with the exception text:
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
System.Private.CoreLib
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Private.CoreLib.dll
----------------------------------------
myawesomeproject
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Location: 
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\8.0.7\System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\8.0.7\System.Windows.Forms.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.Specialized
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Collections.Specialized.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Threading.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.TraceSource
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Collections.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.Common
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\8.0.7\System.Drawing.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Win32.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.Thread
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Threading.Thread.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\8.0.7\Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms
    Assembly Version: 1.0.2592.51
    Location: 
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core
    Assembly Version: 1.0.2592.51
    Location: 
----------------------------------------
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.ComponentModel.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics.Vectors
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Private.Uri
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Private.Uri.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\8.0.7\Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Memory
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Memory.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.NonGeneric
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.ThreadPool
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Loader
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.7\System.Runtime.Loader.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************

The application had a requirement to write to a text file, but I have since deleted it from the latest builds.
The server has the .net 8.0 hosting bundle and the .net 8.0 x64 desktop runtime installed.


JIC if you move the publish directory on the source machine and run the app from it - does it work? 2) Can you please share the full publish command you have used (and if you have used the publish profile file - add it too)?


I've added the publish profile, @GuruStron , but it is irrelevant as I have published nearly every variation and still received the same error, with, or without the uploading the publish folder too.

@sanepete The quickest (but also potentially the most painful) way to resolve this is to use WinDbg with SOS (which stands for "Son of Strike" - and not the nautical term).

The answer, though not obvious, was simple when I learned it.
I hope it helps other people with the same problem.
When using the webview2 nuget package, the host machine also requires the webview2 runtime to be installed.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-edge/webview2

As you've discovered, by default, .NET does not write useful error-details to the Windows Application Event Log: seeing a FileNotFoundException is useless unless you also have the .StackTrace, the .Data dictionary, and relevant members (like FileName) - and the whole chain of InnerException objects.

While .NET has a great stock logging framework in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging with praiseworthy logging-sinks like Serilog, and you should be using them anyway, it is fortunate that that you can simply MsgBox-debug your way out of this, and improve the end-user UX, with just a few changes to your Program.cs:

Wire-up event-handlers for the in-box events concerned with unhandled exceptions:

These functions will be invoked whenever there's an unhandled exception (like that FileNotFoundException) that .NET or WinForms throws upwards (such as exceptions thrown by your code when it's called by WinForms without a (sensible) try/catch - as well as unexpected exceptions thrown by the runtime or your dependencies.
Specifically:

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException - This is the most important event to handle, as it's the last opportunity to observe exceptions in .NET, especially in background threads.
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException - This one is essential once you start using async/await.
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException - This is WinForms-specific, and is called first but only for exceptions in "main threads" or "UI threads" (as opposed to background threads).
System.Windows.Application.DispatcherUnhandledException - This is WPF's equivalent of WinForm's ThreadException




...and in your event-handler, all you need to do is get the Exception object and call ToString() which (in most exception types) will generate a human-readable exception report which you can save to a text-file in %TEMP% and/or stdout/stderr and/or a good ol' fashioned MsgBox.

In older versions of .NET calling Exception.ToString() would (in most cases) just fall-back to Object.ToString() which is just Object.GetType().Name - which is pointless), but since .NET Framework 4.x (4.0? 4.5?) it now returns something actually useful.



Anyway, change your Main method, like so:
namespace MyNamespace
{
  internal static class MyProgram
  {
    [STAThread]
    static Int32 Main()
    {
#if !DEBUG

      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += MyProgram.OnAppDomain_UnhandledException;
      TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += MyProgram.OnTaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;
      Application.ThreadException += MyProgram.OnWinForms_ThreadException;

#endif

      // 

//    try // Uncomment this `try` at your discretion.
      {
          ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
          using( Form f = new MyForm() ) // <-- This isn't necessary, but I do it because it's a habit of mine.
          {
              Application.Run( f );
          }

          return 0;
      }
//    catch
//    {
//        return 1;
//    }
    }

#if !DEBUG

    private static void OnAppDomain_UnhandledException( object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e )
    {
        if( e.ExceptionObject is Exception ex ) DumpException( ex );
    }

    private static void OnWinForms_ThreadException( object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e )
    {
        DumpException( e.Exception );
    }

    private static void OnTaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException( object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e )
    {
        DumpException( e.Exception );
    }

    private static void DumpException( Exception ex )
    {
        try
        {
            String report = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString( "o", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ) + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.ToString() ?? "(Exception.ToString returned null)";
            
            String tempFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
            File.WriteAllText( path: tempFilePath, contents: report );

            _ = MessageBox.Show(
                owner: null,
                text : $"A wild \"{ex.GetType().Name}\" appears!\r\n\r\nPikachu used \"save exception report\" to \"{tempFilePath}\".\r\n\r\nIt's super effective.",
                caption: "Oh dear...",
                buttons: MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                icon: MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                defaultButton: MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                options: (MessageBoxOptions)0
            );

            // TODO: Consider changing the above MessageBox to a Yes/No prompt that will open the saved report file (tempFilePath) in Notepad if the user clicks Yes.
        }
        catch( Exception metaEx )
        {
            // If a meta-exception happens there isn't much you can do except show a Win32 MessageBox... but it's better than nothing:

            _ = MessageBox.Show(
                owner: null,
                text : "Failed to dump exception information - this should never happen:\r\n\r\n" + metaEx.ToString(),
                caption: "Oh dear...",
                buttons: MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                icon: MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                defaultButton: MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                options: (MessageBoxOptions)0
            );
        }
    }
#endif
  } // class
} // namespace



Note the use of #if !DEBUG which means these event-handlers won't exist (let-alone be wired-up) inside a DEBUG build, which means these handlers won't interfere with VS or your debugger.

The above copypastable code can be significantly improved, without much effort, by...

Using .NET's built-in Trace-Logging support (e.g. Trace.WriteLine, Debug.WriteLine, etc) - no additional libs needed.
Consider writing to EventLog anyway, but be aware that you need to first register your program/application with the Windows Event Log Service which requires elevation.
Note that MessageBox.Show is limited to ~1000 characters, while a typical exception report will (in my experience) be on the order of tens-of-kilobytes, so consider replacing the  MessageBox.Show with some other unlikely to fail Win32 functionality for showing long strings to the user.
Consider also adding if( Debugger.IsAttached ) Debugger.Break(); to the DumpException method so you can at-least try to debug the situation before the process is torn-down.



